Statistical test for independent and non-independent data together?
Aim
I would like to compare the prevalence rates of some common mental disorders (CMD) between the findings of several authors (Studies 1 to 5). All of the studies are observational. Four of them are cross-sectional and one is longitudinal (Study 4).
Issue
I cannot use the Chi-squared test of independence because the longitudinal study violates the assumption of independence of observations.
Example
The table below shows an example of the collected data.



Study
n
CMD1 (%)
CMD2 (%)
CMD3 (%)




Study 1
54
NA
NA
26.0


Study 2
198
25.0
19.9
27.0


Study 3
278
38.0
40.0
25.0


Study 4 - T1
595
27.0
31.0
3.6


Study 4 - T2
504
21.0
33.0
3.4


Study 4 - T3
374
22.0
35.0
4.9


Study 5
208
20.3
NA
NA



Main question

Knowing that Study 4 is a longitudinal study, thus violating the assumption of independence of observations, what are the best suited analyses to check whether there is a statistically significant difference between studies for CMD1, CMD2, and CMD3?

Secondary questions

If there are more than one analysis, which one would be best suited and why?
Should I consider Bayesian test(s) in favour of frequentist ones?


YOu have an additional issue, missing data (in Studies 1 and 5). Is it because thiese CMD's were not observed (then entry should be 0, noy NA), or because researchers did not collect this data? Also, are the values in the CMD columns counts (of subjects showing the CMD), or percentages, or ?

Thanks for your comment @jginestet. Indeed Study 1 did not measure CMD1 and CMD2, and Study 5 did not measure CMD2 and CMD3. Can I really replace NA with zeros? Would that be correct statistically as they are numbers? Moreover, most of the stat software/packages do handle missing data (e.g., na.rm = TRUE in R). Thanks to your remark, I added the % sign in the column titles to indicate how to interpret the numerals.

BY all means do not replace them by 0's. If they were not part of these studies, they are truly NA's.

As far as the longitudinal study is concerned, if there was no intervention of any kind between the time points, I would just average the 3 time points (in terms of counts, not proportions, to account for the attrition). You may also average only the first 2 time points (very little attrition between them; but a lot of attrition by T3; so subjects at T3 are "self selecting" which may introduce a bias). Alternatively, I would just use T1 (assuming it is a baseline of sorts). From that point on, you can use 3 contingency tables (1 for each CMD), of slightly different sizes (to account for the missing data). Solve with Fisher-exact and/or $\chi^2$ (I would do both, just to see if I get different answers, which I would not expect as your sample sizes are sufficiently large). You can decide then to use a multiple comparison correction or not (I probably would).
As an aside, looking at CMD3, Study4 observed ~4%. The other 3 observed ~26%; I would expect this to be significant.
